# Why does the Lyapunov criterion only gives sufficient conditions for stability?

Tags: control-theory, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I am studying stability for control systems, and I have written in the notes of my professor that the **Lyapunov Criterion** only gives sufficient conditions for stability, and not necessary and sufficient.

Can someone explain to me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a linear system it does provide necessary and sufficient conditions for stability, for a general non-linear system it's not the case because failure of a chosen Lyapunov function to satisfy all the conditions for stability does not mean that the corresponding equilibrium point is not stable. It (may) just indicate that the chosen Lyapunov function is not good enough. For example take this dynamical system $$\ddot{x}(t)=-\sin x-a \dot{x}(t)~~,~~a\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$$ Which is $$\begin{align}\dot{x}_1&=x_2 \\ \dot{x}_2&=-\sin x_1-ax_2 \end{align}$$ Choose two different Lyapunov function $$\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \ni (x_1,x_2) \mapsto V_1(x_1,x_2):=\left( 1-\cos x_1 \right)+x_2^2 \in \mathbb{R} \tag{L.1}$$ 
$$\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \ni (x_1,x_2) \mapsto V_2(x_1,x_2):=\left( 1-\cos x_1 \right)+\frac{x_2^2}{2} \in \mathbb{R} \tag{L.2}$$ 
See what you get using these two different Lyapunov functions

Comment: Shouldn't this argument also hold for linear systems? Namely, not all positive definite Lyapunov functions have a time derivative that is negative (semi-) definite given that the linear system that is exponentially stable.

Comment: Well the more general statement is: An autonomous linear system $\dot{x}=Ax$ is stable iff, for any PD $Q\in\text{Sym}(n;\mathbb{R})$ there exists a PD $P\in\text{Sym}(n;\mathbb{R})$ s.t $A^{\top}P+PA=-Q$.

Comment: Yes that's true, my English got me here. Finding at-least one PD function with lie derivative neg def does the job

Comment: Actually the situation for linear and nonlinear systems is quite similar, except that in the linear case there exists a constructive method to find a Lyapunov function, if one exists.

Comment: @Pait sure, apologies for the confusion caused

Answer (score 4):

The reason why the conditions are only sufficient is that failure OF A GIVEN FUNCTION to be a Lyapunov function for a system does not mean that no other Lyapunov function exists. This is valid for both linear and nonlinear systems.

There exist converse Lyapunov theorems (the original ones due to Massera, if memory serves me right) establishing that, if a system is stable, then a Lyapunov function exists. The proof in the nonlinear case is neither trivial not completely constructive.

In the case of linear system, there exists a recipe for constructing a Lyapunov function, which consists in solving the Lyapunov matrix equation. Thus if the equation does not provide a Lyapunov function, none exists, and the system is not stable. Apart from existence of the constructive method, the situations for linear and nonlinear systems are quite similar, technicalities aside.